# Bash: convert 100,000+ characters to decimal format?

Tags: shell-script, debian, ubuntu, command-line, scripting

I'm looking for a quick and not-so CPU intensive solution to convert 100,000+ lines of text into decimal format.

```bsh
# random ascii
string='QPWOEIRUTYALSKDJFHGZMXNCBV,./;[]75498053$#!@*&^%(*'

convert () {
    for ((b=0; b<${#string}; b++ ))
    do
        # convert to dec, append colon character, add to array
        arr+=$(printf '%d,' "'${string:$b:1}");
    done;
    # show array contents
    printf '%s' "${arr[@]::-1}"
}

time convert
```

The above works well for short lines, the task is completed in less than a second:

```bsh
$ ./stackexchange.sh

81,80,87,79,69,73,82,85,84,89,65,76,83,75,68,74,70,72,71,90,77,88,78,67,66,86,44,46,47,59,91,93,55,53,52,57,56,48,53,51,36,35,33,64,42,38,94,37,40,42
real    0m0.059s
user    0m0.032s
sys     0m0.016s
```

But it's not a viable solution for files that contain many characters. The below function causes my CPU to spike and basically never completes the task. Well, I press Ctrl+c to stop it after several minutes. Here's the same script with a modified `string` variable.

```bsh
# random ascii
string="$(cat /tmp/100000-characters.txt)"

convert () {
    for ((b=0; b<${#string}; b++ ))
    do
        arr+=$(printf '%d,' "'${string:$b:1}");
    done;
    printf '%s' "${arr[@]::-1}"
}

time convert
```

I tried a while loop, as well. It managed to convert the 100,000 characters file but still takes a long time to complete.

```bsh
string="$(cat /tmp/100000-characters.txt)"

convert () {
    # iteracte through each like 
    while read -r -n1 char; do
        arr+=$(printf '%d,' "'$char");
    done <<< "$string"
    
    printf '%s' "${arr[@]::-3}"
}
time convert
```

**Is there an elegant/simple solution to convert a massive text file into colon-seperated decimal values?**

Comment: is your input file just a single line or many? If many, what do you want to do with the newlines? Ignore them, print their ASCII value, or cause a newline in the output? In your example, you're just reading the whole input into memory, so I guess you want to print the newlines as `10`, too? What about character encoding, is the input just ASCII characters, or do you have UTF-8 too? (or heaven forbid, something entirely different).

Comment: This task will be a lot slower in bash compared to other languages. Perl would be a good choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -nE 'say join ",", map ord, split //' < file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line and runs the code for each line
- [split](http://p3rl.org/split) on an empty regex `//` splits the input to individual characters
- [map](http://p3rl.org/map) maps each character to its [ord](http://p3rl.org/ord)
- [join](http://p3rl.org/join) creates a string back from the characters, inserting commas between them
- [say](http://p3rl.org/say) outputs the result

More tweaking might be needed if you don't want to process the input line by line.

Comment: I think that still needs to generate a list in memory, so if the input is one reaaally long line, it might have issues.

Comment: Yes, you might need to specify the `-0` or similar, but I don't know the details.

Comment: @user427459: As you like. BTW, it took 0.3secs to process 100_000 bytes.

Comment: @user427459, _only_ Bash? Not e.g. standard tools like awk? awk is included in Busybox, for example

Comment: You might want to add `-l` to "autochomp" each line.

Comment: @glennjackman: It depends on how newlines should be treated which wasn't specified. Also, replace `say` with `print` after `-l`.

Answer (score 2):

The vast majority of your time is spent constructing the array, which you appear only to do to remove a colon at the end. Instead, try just using a flag and avoiding building up an array altogether, which is significantly faster:

```
#!/bin/bash

string='QPWOEIRUTYALSKDJFHGZMXNCBV,./;[]75498053$#!@*&^%(*'

convert() {
    local first=1
    for ((b=0; b<${#string}; b++ )); do
        (( first )) && first=0 || printf ,
        printf '%d' "'${string:$b:1}"
    done
}

time convert
```

Here are comparison times. First, your initial solution with 1000 characters:

```
real  0m0.454s
user  0m0.439s
sys   0m0.057s
```

And this solution with 1000 characters:

```
real  0m0.148s
user  0m0.147s
sys   0m0.001s
```

This is about as fast as it's going to get in bash only using builtins. If you can, I urge you to shell out to tools better equipped to handle this, like perl above.

Answer (score 2):

That's the kind of thing `hexdump`/`od` are for:

```
<input hexdump -ve '/1 ",%u"' | tail -c+2
```

for instance.

Note that it prints values of each byte, not the codepoint¹ values of each character like your approach does. On your sample which only contains ASCII characters, that would not  make a difference.

To get the unicode code points, you could convert the input to UCS4 first. Compare:

```
$ printf %s 'Stéphane' | hexdump -ve '/1 ",%u"' | tail -c+2
83,116,195,169,112,104,97,110,101
$ printf %s 'Stéphane' | iconv -t ucs-4le | hexdump -ve '/4 ",%u"' | tail -c+2
83,116,233,112,104,97,110,101
```

Here in a UTF-8 locale with little endian processor (x86), see how the first approach dumps the two bytes of the UTF-8 encoding of the `é` (U+00E9) character (195 and 169) and the second prints 233 (0xe9).

---

<sup>¹ `bash`'s `printf` builtin will typically print the byte value in locales with single-byte charmaps, so give the codepoint in the corresponding charset, and for multi-byte charmaps, will give the wide-char value which on most systems is the Unicode code point</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string is stored in a file named `file` we can use **python** to evaluate the ordinal number of each char.

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fh: s=fh.read()
print(*[ord(c) for c in s.rstrip("\n")], sep=",")
' ./file
```

- file is slurped into the string variable s.
- using a list comprehension construct we loop over the string char-by-char and evaluate the ordinal number of each using the builtin `ord()`, they are then accumulated in an anonymous list which is printed with list separator being a comma.

Alternatively, we can use the gnu versions of the Linux utilities `xargs+grep`. This minimizes the number of calls to printf

```
$ printf '%s\0' "$string"   \
| grep -oz '.'              \
| xargs -r0 printf "'%s\\0" \
| xargs -r0 printf '%d\n'   \
| paste -sd,
```